# looping given max and range

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Given max number and range number, I want print out the following, but as short as possible.  I don't know if this accomplish using IntStream.

input:
max = 36 (or any number)
range = 10 (or any number)

output:
0-9
10-19
20-29
30-35

my code:

```
totalItems=35
rangeMax=10
rangeFrom=0
rangeTo=0
while (true) {
    if(totalItems>rangeTo+rangeMax){
        rangeFrom=rangeTo+1;
        rangeTo=rangeTo+rangeMax;
    } else if(totalItems>rangeTo+1){
        rangeFrom=rangeTo+1;
        rangeTo=rangeTo+(totalItems-rangeFrom);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Your question is currently not showing any attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: I just edited my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void loopingIssue(Integer totalItems, Integer range) {
    IntStream.range(0, totalItems).filter(i -> i % range == 0)
            .mapToObj(e -> mapToGroup(e, totalItems, range))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
}

public static String mapToGroup(Integer e, Integer totalItems, Integer maxRange) {
    if (e + maxRange >= totalItems) {
        return e + "-" + (totalItems - 1);
    } else {
        return e + "-" + (e + maxRange - 1) + ", ";
    }

}
```